# Diamond Shape Topology on a Flat Surface With No Deformation Planned

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

Is it ok to use this type junction for reduce this shape on a Flat Surface? There will be No Deformation Planned to happen on it.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). It's absolutely fine to use any topology you want if it works. Related: https://topologyguides.com/loop-reduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop flow being good or bad is mostly depend on what you want to do with it.
on a flat surface that does not deform, and it has support loop on top and bottom so it's good to me at least.
on a high deformed surface it "might" cause problems.

as I see now your model is a hard surface and you did it on a flat surface and I don't thing it will ever deform so you are ok.

some might use their loop flow to make new parts out of it or help make stuff separate or help make textures.